# If someone disarmed Harry, would the Elder wand become theirs?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore, deathly-hallows

In the *Half-Blood Prince*, Draco Malfoy gained ownership of the Elder wand by disarming Dumbldore when he was holding the Elder wand.

Could someone have used Expelliarmus on Harry to take ownership of the wand, even if he didn’t have it on him? Because Draco Malfoy had ownership, and then Harry got ownership by stealing Draco's normal (original) wand.

Sorry if this is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not confusing at all. You almost answered your own question.
Draco got ownership of Elder wand by disarming Dumbledore using Expelliarmus.
Harry got ownership of Draco's original wand & the Elder wand by snatching the wand from Draco's hands.
At this point, whatever wands were in Draco's ownership came under Harry's ownership.
So if anybody disarmed Harry using Expelliarmus or snatched any wand that was under Harry's ownership, all the wands under Harry's ownership would come under the said person's ownership.

Winner Takes All